# How's the function space in page number?

Tags: javascript, html, css, encoding, blogger

In inspect element, I added a space functions and it was succesfull.

[Image of added space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbM93.png)

I put it between tag `<a/>` and `</span>`. It's correct location and not different with inspect element section.

[redirect function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4JSo.png)

But it is still failing all over and over...

[Incorrect space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBBYJ.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Use `&nbsp;` entity to add spaces in between tags, use `<br>` to add line-break to your tags

Either way you can use css to this to add spacing. In your span:

**CSS**

```
span.showpageNum {
 margin-right:10px; // or any px you want to adjust spacing
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Really muchas gracias laurence... it works! May God bless you..